# How to send 887 Bytes via Com-port in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, infrared

I am using .NET 6 LTS with System.IO.Ports 8.0.

I try to send 887 Bytes using an IR transmitter. P is my Com-port. The first 873 bytes are "wakeup" bytes:

```
for (uint u = 1; u <= 873; u++)
{
    Byte[] bb = { 0x0E };
    P.Write(bb, 0, 1);
}
```

The problem is, in this case i will only receive (and as it happens send) 425 bytes of those 873. Always this exact number. I also tried using an Array with 873 times 0x0E - this doesn't change anything.

If I add a dirty delay, I receive all bytes:

```
for (uint u = 1; u <= 873; u++)
{
    Byte[] bb = { 0x0E };
    P.Write(bb, 0, 1);
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

I do also receive all bytes, if I do `for (uint u = 1; u <= 200; u++)` multiple times with a `Thread.Sleep(1);` in between those `for`.

Unluckily those dirty delays will cause my receiving device not to wake up, because the sequence takes to long (Should be like 4 secs in 2400 Bd 8N1, but is now >14sec).

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like your receiving device doesn't have enough buffer to keep up.  Doing a short sleep every Nth byte seems like a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @BenVoigt This should not be the problem. I am replicating a serial protocoll from a discontinued software, which is able to send this exact data on the exact COM-port and the device receives it.

I even tried to use a real serial wire with 2 ttl ftdi adapters. Input-buffer is not the problem.

Comment: Have you used a logic analyzer to capture the timing of the original software's transmissions as well as your own timing and compare?

Comment: Ignoring the Handshake property is a standard oversight.  Sounds like it is set/defaults to Handshake.None now and should be Handshake.RequestToSend